# julia/ JuMP: no method matching ndims

Tags: optimization, julia

right now I want to get myself more familiar within the filed of linear programming using julia/JuMP. More specifically, I'm trying to implement the algorithm for benders decomposition. Since I'm stuck at certain parts, I wanted to look into other implementations which did similar before. Fortunately, I could find one in the official tutorial section of JuMP: https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/stable/tutorials/Optimization%20concepts/benders_decomposition/

https://github.com/jump-dev/JuMP.jl/blob/master/docs/src/tutorials/Optimization%20concepts/benders_decomposition.jl

Unfortunately I can not execute it. It crashes within the first iteration:

```
with fm_current = 1.0e6
x_current = [0.0, 0.0]
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching ndims(::AffExpr)
Closest candidates are:
  ndims(::GenericQuadExpr) at C:\Users\Laurenz\.julia\packages\JuMP\Xrr7O\src\quad_expr.jl:54
  ndims(::Base.Generator) at generator.jl:53
  ndims(::JuMP.Containers.VectorizedProductIterator) at C:\Users\Laurenz\.julia\packages\JuMP\Xrr7O\src\Containers\vectorized_product_iterator.jl:73
  ...
Stacktrace:
```

all of my julia packages are up to date.

It crashes within the MutableArithmetics.jl [in this line:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaHC6.png)

Maybe someone has this code already running or could simply try to run it. Would be much appreciated!
Thank you:)

Comment: Please, add the version of Julia you are using and versions of packages you have installed.
You can obtain it by typing `] st -m` into Julia REPL.

Comment: I was updating jump again last week. Now it is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine with `julia 1.5.4` and following versions of packages

```
(jump_playground) pkg> st
Status `C:\Projects\jump_playground\Project.toml`
  [60bf3e95] GLPK v0.14.12
  [4076af6c] JuMP v0.21.9
  [8dfed614] Test
```

sometimes when you update versions of packages, you need to restart the julia REPL. Also, if you are using some much older version of julia or the package it may not work, in that case it's good to update using `] up`.

Comment: I was updating julia JuMP again last week. Now it is working! I guess it was just some build in between which could not execute the example! Thank you! :)